# Dual Boot: Windows XP alongside Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, windows, multi-boot

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Which should I install first, Windows XP or Windows 7?](https://superuser.com/questions/39480/which-should-i-install-first-windows-xp-or-windows-7)

I have already installed Windows 7, and now i want to install Windows XP alongside Windows 7.

Is it possible? And, If YES. Than whats the right way to do it?

Thanks.

Comment: Quite possible. Without going into details google: "Install xp after windows 7" ... there is a mass of tutorials floating around.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The recommended way would be to use [Windows XP mode](http://www.microsoft.com/windows/virtual-pc/download.aspx) inside Windows 7, to run it as an integrated virtual machine. This will allow you to run your Windows XP applications without having to actually reboot into Windows XP. In my experience this works well, but it does depend on your machines specifications.

If in fact you wanted to physically dual boot, for "bare metal performance" of Windows XP, then you'll have far less trouble with the setup if you first install Windows XP then Windows 7.

Otherwise in the reverse order the Windows XP installation will clobber the Windows 7 boot, and you'll need to take steps to restore it.

Try following the steps from this [LifeHacker](http://lifehacker.com/5126781/how-to-dual-boot-windows-7-with-xp-or-vista) post there are many other guides available via a search; [example](http://www.bing.com/search?q=Windows+XP+Windows+7+dual+boot).